# Clairaut's Theorem, $f_{xyy}=f_{yxy}=f_{yyx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f$ is a two variable function in $x,y$. $f_{xyy},f_{yxy},f_{yyx}$ are defined and continuous. Then $f_{yxy}=f_{yyx}$ can be proved by applying the theorem to $f_y$.
But to finish the proof, we need to show $f_{xy},f_{yx}$ are continuous since then by the theorem again, $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ and $f_{xyy}=f_{yxy}$.

But I am not sure how to prove $f_{xy},f_{yx}$ are continuous from $f_{xyy},f_{yxy},f_{yyx}$ continuous.

Comment: $f_{xyy}$ is a derivative of $f_{xy}$ with respect to $y$ and $f_{yxy}$ is a derivative of $f_{yx}$ with respect to $y$ as well. If $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ aren't even continuous, how can they be differentiable?..

Comment: But isn't there an example showing partial derivatives don't necessarily imply 'continuous'?